# Python 3 String Formatting Issues

Tags: python-3.x, string, formatting

I have run into an issue where i can't format a string to be printed.
The function is suppossed to convert Binary into Text which is does brilliantly but the printed out result is formatted all the way the right and not the left.

I have tried resolving this by looking up how to format the string but im getting no luck. Im hoping someone can resolve this issue for me.

Heres the code:

```
        elif Converter_Choice2 == str(3):
            def Bin_to_Txt():
                print("\nYour Message in Binary:")
                bin_input = input("")
                binary_int = int(bin_input, 2)
                byte_number = binary_int.bit_length() + 7 // 8

                binary_array = binary_int.to_bytes(byte_number, "big")
                ascii_text = binary_array.decode()

                clear()
                print("\nYour Message in Text:")
                print(ascii_text)
                
            Bin_to_Txt()
```

I tried different ways to format it but im still new to Python 3. I tried putting "ascii_text" into another string to format it, so i could print that string but it didn't work.

```
        ascii_text_formatted = ("{:<15}".format(ascii_text))
        print(ascii_text_formatted)
```

Some advice for this would be great.

Heres a quick Binary code that can be used: 0100100001100101011011000110110001101111

The decoded version should say "Hello".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find the answer. If anyone else has this issue or something similar try this:

The issue was the variable "binary_array" was printing out invisible numbers before the printed answer in this case "Hello". Due to this it would print "Hello" all the way to the right as the invisible numbers where in front of it.

To fix this issue i added [34:] at the end of the "binary_array" string to remove those invisible numbers from the print. By adding [34:] it means the first 34 characters/numbers wont be printed even if they are invisible. So this can be any number that you need it to be. For example if i changed 34 to 35 it would remove the "H" from "Hello" and print "ello".

Heres some screenshots of the function block and printed responces from before and after adding [34:].

https://i.stack.imgur.com/K41wC.jpg